# httpservletrequest.getservletcontext.getrealpath content lost after amazon ec2 restart

Tags: jakarta-ee, amazon-ec2, tomcat7

I have tomcat 7 running on an amazon instance.

I'm saving some file using the class

```
@POST
public BooleanResponse foo(@Context HttpServletRequest req,
        FormDataMultiPart data) {
  String fileString = req.getservletcontext().getrealpath("/images");                   
  File filePath = new File(fileString + File.separator + filename);
  saveImage(inputStream, filePath);
```

this works fine!

the trouble is that every time I restart my amazon instance, all my images files will be lost :(

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Thx

Comment: What is the value of fileString?

Comment: Is your EC2 instance using an EBS volume or an Instance Store ?